# boto3 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'

Tags: python, boto3

I am working with Python version 2.7 and boto3 , but cannot import boto3 library .

My Python path is

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

When I look under

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I see boto3 installed . But I keep getting this error

```
 import boto3
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 14, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 60, in <module>
    from org.python.core import PyStringMap
  File "/Users/user/git_repos/aws-boto3/org.py", line 7, in <module>
    client = boto3.client('organizations')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'
```

Python version: 2.7

boto3 Version: 1.13.13

botocore Version: 1.16.13

What am I missing?

Here is the code

```
import boto3

print('hello')
```

Note that from a python commandline I can import boto3 this fails when I run `python hello.py`

Comment: Can you show the code where you want to use `boto3`?

Comment: I dont have a boto3.py in my working directory

Comment: @Marcin added the code

Comment: interesting find , this was another python file, I deleted it and I can run without issues! Thank you!

Comment: Ok. I will make answer then, for future reference if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments, the issue turned out to be caused by  a presence of some **unwanted file**:

> /Users/user/git_repos/aws-boto3/org.py

**Removal** of the file was the solution to the problem.

Comment: and how did you find the culprit file

Comment: @JamesWierzba Hi. It was in the error message in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo find / -type f -name *boto* 2>>/dev/null` - Will help in getting such file and move or rename other than boto*. So as to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different IDE. I had this error on multiple IDE's but on pycharm I didn't get the error. There's many different reasons for this error it seems.